# is it possible to remove a Table row based on the data attribute

Tags: jquery

On Click of delete button is it possible to remove the table row based on the data attribute ?

This is my js code

```
$(document).on("click", ".deletevideo", function(event) {
    if (confirm("Are You Sure to Remove This Video From This PAC?") == true) {
        var video_id = $(this).data('videoid');
    }

    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/261/)

Comment: Why not simple `$(this).closest('tr').remove();`? http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/262/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to `tr` element which needs to be deleted.

```
if (confirm("Are You Sure to Remove This Video From This PAC?")) {
    //Travese up to get the row and delete
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/262/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the Index of the `tr` for which you want the `data-attribute` from

```
$('#tableid tr:eq(0)'); // First row in table

$('#tableid tr:eq(1)'); // Second row in table
```

Because there might be multiple rows in the table

```
var theRowId = $('#tableid tr:eq(1)').attr('data-id'); // Get the Second Row id
$('#tableid tr#'+theRowId).remove();  // Remove the row with id
```

OR if you know the ID of the Row.. simply do this

```
$('#tableid tr[data-id="'+theRowId+'"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding my two cents following @Satpal's solution.

If anyone using Fetch API then this (Delete) sample might help too.

HTML (Thymeleaf in my case):

```
<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" th:onclick="deletedbfile([[${myfile.id}]], this);">Delete</a></td>
```

JavaScript:

```
function deletedbfile(id, Object) {
    fetch('/deletedbfile/' + id, {
        method: 'DELETE',
    })
        .then((response) => {
            //alert(response.status);
            if (response.status == 204) {
                Object.closest('tr').remove();
            }
            console.log('Success:', response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
}
```