# How to remove td from a tr inside a table

Tags: jquery

On click of the remove button , i am adding this tr to table 1 
Before adding it to the table 1 , i need to remove this particular td

```
 <td><a data-videoid="6" class="btn btn-delete removevideo btn-danger ui-link">Remove</a></td>
```

This is my code

```
 $(document).on("click", ".removevideo", function(event)
{


            if (confirm("Are You Sure to Remove This Video From This PAC?") == true)
            {
               var video_id = $(this).data('videoid');
               $(this).closest("tr").removeClass('existingvideos');
               var html = $('#table1 tr[video-id="'+video_id+'"]').prop('outerHTML');
               $('#table1 tr[video-id="'+video_id+'"]').remove();
                  $("#table2 tbody").append(html);

            }        
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;



});
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/271/

Comment: You don't learn, following question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374508/is-it-possible-to-remove-a-table-row-based-on-the-data-attribute

Answer (score 2):

To solve your immediate problem you can use `$(this).closest('td').remove()`. However you can also massively simplify your code by using DOM traversal instead of selecting by the `videoId`. Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".removevideo", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $a = $(this);
    var $tr = $a.closest('tr');

    if (confirm("Are You Sure to Remove This Video From This PAC?")) {
        $tr.removeClass('existingvideos').remove();
        $a.closest('td').remove();
        $("#table2 tbody").append($tr);
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/274/)

Comment: i was managing with $(this).closest("tr").find("td:last").remove(); , but your code loks more good .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).closest("tr").remove();
```

It will remove the closest tr on which remove is clicked.

Check the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/273/)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var html = $('#table1 tr[video-id="'+video_id+'"] td:not(:last-child)').prop('outerHTML');
```

instead.it eliminates the last column before appending.